# Probability girlfriend receives letter, given that friend can forget to deliver or mail can not deliver it

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

> You deliver your friend a letter to be sent to your girlfriend, to be
>   put in the mail. However, he can forget to put in the mail with
>   probability $0.1$. If he doesn't forget, the probability that the
>   delivery service don't deliver it is $0.1$. Finally, if the letter got
>   sent, the probability that the girlfriend don't receive it is $0.1$
>
> a) If your girlfriend didn't receive the letter, which is the
>   probability that your friend forgot to put it in the mail?

The exercise is asking $P(\mbox{friend forgot | girlfriend didn't receive})$. I'd write this, using bayes theorem, as:

$P(\mbox{friend forgot | girlfriend didn't receive}) = \frac{P(\mbox{girlfriend didn't receive | friend forgot})P(\mbox{friend forgot})}{P(\mbox{something})}$

But I don't know what this something is.

Comment: Remeber Bayes-rule $$P(A|B) = \dfrac{P(B|A)\cdot P(A)}{P(B)}$$ this implies in your case that $P(\text{Something}) = P(\text{Girlfriend didn't recieve})$

Comment: Hmm, it's kinda weird, the last two sentences seems the same? *If he doesn't forget, the probability that the delivery service don't deliver it is 0.1. * seems the same as *Finally, if the letter got sent, the probability that the girlfriend don't receive it is 0.1*